# Why are my CSS styles not applying to my page?

Tags: css, asp.net-core, blazor

I am trying to create a big Blazor app using a combination of CSS and Tailwind CSS.

I wanted to create a few reusable style components such as buttons and I created my own CSS reset file.
They are located in the 'wwwroot/css' directory and linked in the index.html file.

The link is made but the results seem to vary.
Sometimes none of the changes will be made and sometimes only a couple.

For example I can't set the body background to red, but I can set an icon to 100px wide. All from the same page.

When I use the inspect tool in the browser and go through the css, the element will have the records of the css pages I created and the style I am trying to provide. But it just does not take effect.

It tends to work perfectly if I just add the  tags and put the css in there on the same page as the html and code.

What is the correct way to make my styles apply to my page?

Here is an example to show I am picking up the code in my inspector.

mud.blazor.css

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

reset.css

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The relevant part of the generated HTML file looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Meta Data-->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <title>SilhouetteBlazorWebBluetooth</title>
  <base href="/" />
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link href="SilhouetteBlazorWebBluetooth.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/design.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/components.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Tailwind -->
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <!-- Mud Blazor -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
</head>
```

Here you can see my css file and the page this generates, where `background-color: red` is not applied.
[image]

I have tried moving the folders and deleting any caches that may get in the way

Comment: Are there perhaps other styles that take precedence? Or does the body not have dimensions, so you can't see the background color? Otherwise you might need to show more context (exactly what you see in the browser developer tools, how you link the css files, ...) for other people to help more.

Comment: I have been testing that through the inspector and adding the !important tag. no effect. even my button class isnt working and there is nothing to override that

Comment: Then you might want to [edit] your question and add more details. Show us the lines of code, where you link the css files (ideally the whole `<head>` section). Show a screenshot of your page and the browsers developer tools. Show us what you tried and what exactly is not working, instead of describing it to us.

Comment: Try Ctrl+F5, this is probably just a cache problem

Comment: I removed the second question from your post, as each question should focus on a specific problem you are facing. If the above comment did not solve it for you, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: Mudblazor is overwitting your CSS, a simple `!important` should do the trick, if not, add a class to your body and set the CSS class `body.myClass`, it should be on top of priorities since it's a more specific style

Comment: TOO much CSS is the bane of all attempts at styling properly. IMHO if you find yourself doing `!important` find some way to remove things or re-order them - looks like you have at least 3 that do "reset" type CSS in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order in which css files are linked is important. If two different files change a property with the same [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), the last file takes priority.

In your case the Mud Blazor styling takes precedence over your reset.css file. You can see that in the developer tools. There, your `background-color: red` is crossed out, and the property `background-color: var(--mud-palette-background)` is not.

I generally prefer to include css files from libraries at the top and override the styles in my own files further down. Additionally, you could use the styles from these libraries to your advantage, and instead just set the variables they use to your preference:

```css
:root {
  --mud-palette-background: red;
}
```